# Validate length of checkbox selected in Jquery and rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a collection_check_boxes and I have some classes for it, I want to do a validation that cannot select more than 5 checkboxes, but im not completely sure how to get the length all , of my checkbox selected

I did it in Jquery, that is working, I just need help with the validation in Javascript

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class FavoriteFormVenues {
  constructor() {
    this.attachEvents()
  }

  attachEvents() {
    $(document).on('change', '.js-favorite-form-venues', event =>
      this.handleTypeChange(event)
    )
  }

  handleTypeChange(event) {
    let $venue = $(event.target)
    let $venueItem = $('label[for="profile_venue_ids_'+$venue.val()+'"]').find($('.js-select-favorite'));
    if(($venue).prop('checked')) {
      $venueItem.addClass("border-4 border-celeste-700");
    } else {
      $venueItem.removeClass("border-4 border-celeste-700");
    }
  }


}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  new FavoriteFormVenues()
});
```

Just have the possibility to a user to select maximun 5 venue with prop checked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo-class for the selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

```
if ($('some-selector:checked').length() <= 5)
  something...
else
  error...
end
```